# Metricbeat System process permissions needed on windows

Tags: windows, elasticsearch, elastic-stack, metricbeat

We are using metricbeat system process module to monitor all processes running on windows platforms. Metricbeat is only able to get himself process information. We want to get all processes information.
What permissions do it need to get all the processes in windows operative system?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a bug in metricbeat that fail when executing metricbeat with non-admin user. Oppened on https://github.com/elastic/gosigar/pull/121